# Git - maintaining a deployment branch parallel to master

Tags: git

EDIT

The short question is : how can I merge master into a parallel branch (say, "deploy") without keeping any of the previous content of this other branch. Basically I want to force a copy of master into "deploy" every time I merge.

ORIGINAL QUESTION (for background information)

I'm using git for developping a website. I keep a working version in the "master" branch, that I push to a test site while developping. In "master" I have unminified JS files that I need to edit while developping (among many other files).

When I need to upload a new version to the production site, I obviously need to have the newest version of Master, but I also need to perform some cleaning up (i.e. minify my JS files and remove the unminified files).

Is there a way I can maintain the same "Deploy" branch in git, into which I would "merge" the new changes in "master", but ignoring in fact whatever was in "Deploy" before the merge ? I'd be sure to have an up-to-date copy of "master" from which I could do my cleaning up and push to production.

I tried to the git's documentation and thought that "ours" or "theirs" were sort of doing what I wanted, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I read your question twice, and I still don't understand with the deploy and cleaning up. Why would that be a responsibility of git?

Comment: It's not. It's just to explain why I would need such a branch. Shall I remove reference to deployment ?

Comment: Please make sure we can read and understand it based on no background knowledge. But please keep in there the goal that you actually want to reach. But maybe you can explain what is on each branch and what your prefered outcome is.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Git problem, it's a deployment problem. See for example [Should minified CSS be stored in Git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329744/should-minified-css-be-stored-in-git) on the Software Engineering site.

Your Git repository should contain all *source* files necessary to compile your deployment artifacts. A deployment should be reproducible (perhaps not byte-by-byte, but functionally identical) from those source files.

You *could* opt to store your deployment artifacts, packaged or not (e.g. a zip file), in a separate "deploy" branch or a different repository (or storage system) altogether.

All in all it sounds like you need a deployment process, not a Git process. You could probably trivially write the deployment task up in a batch script, which checks out your sources, builds the desired deployment artifacts and packages those up for deployment.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I'd never thought of it this way.